# Initiate login activity by one click

Tags: android, facebook, button, authentication

I am working on a custom button which enable Facebook login. What I am coding gave me a result which I need to tap the button twice only it will start the activity.

I was trying to work on it through adjusting the position of startActivity() function in different way. And I found that I can make it to become initialization through placing the startActivity() function just after the finding of view for button bLogin.

Logically, it seems not right as no user will start to proceed to the next activity before login.

Any solution on this? Thank you in advance.

For your information, here are my MainActivity java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
GraphRequest graphRequest;
com.facebook.login.LoginManager fbLoginManager;
Button bLogin;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//new activity from login page
public void chatbox (View view){
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, tabviewChatbox.class);
    fbLoginManager = com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance();
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

    //only start activity if login success
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
        }
    });
}

public void graphRequest(AccessToken accessToken) {
    graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            Log.d("response", response.toString());
        }
    });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,birthday,friends");
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
}

//Function calling for integration of font awesome, can directly put icon inside default button by typing name
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

}